# Unmute autoplay video on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, touch, html5-video

I have a website that has a muted autoplay video in the background.
I have this:

```js
var vidSource = document.getElementById('vidSource');

vidSource.setAttribute('src', 'images/background-mobile.webm');

window.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {

$('#backgroundVid').prop('muted', !$('#backgroundVid').prop('muted'));

});
```

```html
  <video id="backgroundVid" loop muted autoplay class="videoPlayer">
    <source id="vidSource" type="video/webm" />
  </video>
```

It works if I run the code in a click event with a desktop browser.
However, with Chrome for Android, the video freezes when the touch event is triggered.
I guess the same happens with Safari for iOS, aswell with many other mobile browsers.

I know videos need to be muted so that they can be autoplayed on mobile, but how can the user unmute them afterwards? (e.g.: by touching the screen or by clicking on an unmute button)

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue on Chrome for Android. Mobile Safari does not behave the same way.


The problem is only with `touchstart`. `touchend` and `click` does not pause the video.


Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I can confirm the issue on Android (8 through 10) with either Chrome or Samsung browsers. More precisely, it only occurs if the un-muting tap is the first interaction after page load (i.e. initial or reload, interestingly *not* navigation or even a Javascript reload). Sounds like a browser or system bug to me.

Comment: Using "touchend" is a feasible workaround for me, thanks @Daghall!